# Swap certain lines in notepad++ automatically

Tags: automation, notepad++, swap, lines, sqf

I got this big .SQF file which is generated by the 3d editor of ARMA2 (a game).
This editor is bugged in a lot of ways, but it's the only "easy" way to add custom map content. A big example is this problem:

The editor writes certain lines to a so called .SQF file. Every object consists of a few lines. The problem is, that the order of the lines is not always being written in the correct order. It results in objects being spawned incorrectly. When having more than 1000+ objects, and thus more than 10000+ lines, it will become a massive task to make the lines of each object in the right order.

Here is an example of a few objects in the file:

```
_vehicle_372 = objNull;
if (true) then
{
_this = createVehicle ["MAP_asf2_1_1000", [13661.608, 2976.1057, 4.9591064e-005], [], 0, "CAN_COLLIDE"];
  _vehicle_372 = _this;
  _this setDir 40.844734;
  _this setPos [13661.608, 2976.1057, 4.9591064e-005];
};

_vehicle_378 = objNull;
if (true) then
{
  _this = createVehicle ["MAP_dum_mesto2", [13689.696, 2863.1313, 0.17608854], [], 0, "CAN_COLLIDE"];
  _vehicle_378 = _this;
  _this setDir -30.116863;
  _this setVectorUp [0, 0, 1];
  _this setPos [13689.696, 2863.1313, 0.17608854];
};

_vehicle_380 = objNull;
if (true) then
{
  _this = createVehicle ["MAP_dum_mesto_in", [13686.867, 2907.3464, -0.009554117], [], 0, "CAN_COLLIDE"];
  _vehicle_380 = _this;
  _this setDir -63.79903;
  _this setPos [13686.867, 2907.3464, -0.009554117];
};

_vehicle_384 = objNull;
if (true) then
{
  _this = createVehicle ["MAP_HouseBlock_B1", [13722.756, 2839.5999, 0.29589382], [], 0, "CAN_COLLIDE"];
  _vehicle_384 = _this;
  _this setDir -216.63187;
  _this setVectorUp [0, 0, 1];
  _this setPos [13722.756, 2839.5999, 0.29589382];
};
```

The lines i like to swap are:

```
_this setVectorUp [0, 0, 1];
```

With:

```
_this setPos [13722.756, 2839.5999, 0.29589382];
```

The setvectorup line values are consistent, but the setPos will contain different coords everytime. (only "_this setPos" remains the same).

Is there a way in notepad++ to automatically swap ALL "_this setvectorup" lines with the "_this setPos" lines?

Comment: please reduce your question to the exact minimal problem you are facing, it would be much easier to help you then

Comment: btw, if you have linux or cygwin on windows you can use 'sort' and 'uniq' utilities to remove duplicated lines or to gather lines from same source (assuming their source is stated at the beginning of the line)

Comment: There's only one question in my post, and it is stated in the bottom. It's pretty short. The rest of the text is just an explanation what the problem is i'm facing. If you can't help me with the question, then please don't bother writing a comment at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the two lines are adjacent then they can be swapped by a search and replace in Notepad++. Set the **Find what** to `^([ \t]*_this setVectorUp.*)\r\n([ \t]*_this setPos.*)$` and the **Replace with** to be `\2\r\n\1`. Ensure that **Regular expression** is selected and the **Don't matches newline** is *not* selected.

The `^` and `$` match the start of the first line and the end of the second and the `\r\n` matches the newline between them. The `[ \t]*` matches the leading whitespace on the lines. (`[ \t]*` is used rather than `\s*` to make it clear to the human reader that CRs and LFs are excluded.) The `.*`matches a sequence of characters that do not include a newline. So the `[ \t]*_this setVectorUp.*` matches on of the lines, similarly for the other line. Enclosing in `(` and `)` remembers the matched lines as **captured** text.

The replacement text reverses the order of the two captured lines and inserts the newline sequence.

This answer also assumes that the two items are exactly two lines. If the items are split over more lines, or if other items are present, then some may not be swapped, or the swap may reorder the wrong items.

Comment: This worked exactly like i wanted it to work, and gave me some new insights on the regular expressions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

```
544
4
-1269

770
4
325

tp@p[score_money_min=10000000,team=default] 96 4 -397
scoreboard teams join VIP @p[r=5]
scoreboard players remove @p money 10000000

23.23.76.109:25565
```